# Calculating change in estimates in logistic regression SAS

Tags: logistic-regression

I need some help with this problem I am trying to solve. I am running a logistic regresssion model. After running the full model, I removed one variable from the full model. I want to see how removing that one variable affected the betas (parameter estimates) of the other variables in the model.

Let's say for example my full model looks like this:

```
proc logistic data=temp;
    class sex race hospital snf;
    model read=sex race hospital snf;
run;

enter code here
```

And the reduced model looks like this (it is without the variable snf

```
proc logistic data=temp;
    class sex race hospital;
    model read=sex race hospital;
run;
```

I want to see how removing snf from the full model changed the betas for other variables in the reduced model.